# AJAX Button Filter Update CODE UPDATE (See new code)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I am writing a website where I want to enable users to filter their graphs by hour, day, week, month.  So I figured I'd put some buttons up allowing them to select what they would want.  Now I don't want the page to refresh I just want the graph to be updated in screen.  So here is what I have it is all in 1 php file.

I have 2 problems:

1)My button select only returns whatever button is the first one declared so in this case it always returns hour no matter what I click.

2)When I do select the button I think I need to reload that part of the page to render the update? I'm not really sure I haven't use AJAX or anything really before.  More or less just trying to string stuff together.

```
<?php
include("chartsphp4free/lib/inc/chartphp_dist.php"); 
$p = new chartphp(); 

if(strcmp($_POST["filter"],"hour")==0){
   //hour
   $sql = "select for hour";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
}

if(strcmp($_POST["filter"],"day")==0){ 
  //day
   $sql = "select for day";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
if(strcmp($_POST["filter"],"week")==0){ 
   //week
   $sql = "select for week";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
if(strcmp($_POST["filter"],"month")==0){ 
   //month
   $sql = "select for month";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
}


    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $dataStuff = [];

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $holder = array($row["time"],$row["clicks"]);
        array_push($dataStuff,$holder);

        }
        $p->data = array($dataStuff);
   }

$p->chart_type = "line"; 

$out = $p->render('c1'); 

?> 


<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script src="chartsphp4free/lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="chartsphp4free/lib/js/chartphp.js"></script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="chartsphp4free/lib/js/chartphp.css"> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
 <form id="formoid" action="testGraph.php" title="" method="post">
       <div>
            <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="Hour"  value="Hour" >
            <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="Day"   value="Day" >
            <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="Week"  value="Week" >
            <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="Month" value="Month" >
        </div>
 </form>
        <div style="width:40%; min-width:450px;"> 
            <?php echo $out; ?> 
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html> 



<script type='text/javascript'>


  /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#formoid").submit(function(event) {

      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();

      /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
      var $form = $( this ),
          url = $form.attr( 'action' );

      /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
      var posting = $.post( url, { filter: $('#submitButton').val() } );
      alert($('#submitButton').val());
      /* Alerts the results */
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        alert('success');
      });
    });
</script>
```

CODE UPDATE: So now the button presses work and it says the correct value however my graph doesn't ever update.  I tried updating the inner html but it gives me an error with the php echo.  Any thoughts on this.

```
<?php

include("chartsphp4free/lib/inc/chartphp_dist.php"); 

$p = new chartphp(); 

if(isset($_POST["filter"])){
  echo $_POST["filter"];
}

if(!isset($_POST["filter"]))
{
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(timeClicked) as clicks, o_ID, EXTRACT(hour from timeClicked) as time FROM adTracker GROUP BY o_ID, time";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
   //hour
if(strcmp($_POST["filter"],"hour")==0)
{
   $sql = "SELECT gour";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
   //day
if(strcmp($_POST["filter"],"day")==0)
{
   $sql = "SELECT day";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
   //week
if(strcmp($_POST["filter"],"week")==0)
{
   $sql = "SELECT week";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
   //month
if(strcmp($_POST["filter"],"month")==0)
{
   $sql = "SELECT month";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
}


    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $dataStuff = [];

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $holder = array($row["time"],$row["clicks"]);
        array_push($dataStuff,$holder);
        }

        $p->data = array($dataStuff);
   }


$p->chart_type = "line"; 

// Common Options 
$p->title = "Chris and Wyn Test"; 
$p->ylabel = "Clicks"; 
$p->xlabel = "Hour";

$p->options["axes"]["yaxis"]["tickOptions"]["prefix"] = ''; 

$out = $p->render('c1'); 

?> 


<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="chartsphp4free/lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="chartsphp4free/lib/js/chartphp.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="chartsphp4free/lib/js/chartphp.css"> 
</head>

<body>


<form id="formoid" action="testGraph.php" title="" method="post">
       <div>
            <input type="submit" class="submitButton" name="Hour"  value="Hour" >
            <input type="submit" class="submitButton" name="Day"   value="Day" >
            <input type="submit" class="submitButton" name="Week"  value="Week" >
            <input type="submit" class="submitButton" name="Month" value="Month" >
        </div>
 </form>

 <div id= "graph1" style="width:40%; min-width:450px;"> 
            <?php echo $out; ?> 
  </div>

</body>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $(".submitButton").click(function(event) {

      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();
            /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
      var $form = $('#formoid'),
          url = $form.attr( 'action' );
      /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
      var posting = $.post( url, { filter: $(this).val() } );
      /* Alerts the results */
       alert($(this).val());
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        alert('success');
        document.getElementById("graph1").innerHTML = '<?php echo $out; ?>';

      });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You have 4 buttons define all with `id="submitButton"` The `id="??"` MUST BE UNIQUE ON A PAGE its like a unique key on a database. As the Swordman says **There can be only one** Thats basic HTML rules

Comment: Look at your browsers javascript debugger (Console) there will be errors!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally a form should have only one `submit` button , but you have multiple submit button. Instead you can use `button type ="button"` .

Also there will be unique id. So you can use `class` as selector and on click use `$(this)`  to get the current target

**HTML**

```
<div>
        <input type="button" class="submitButton" name="Hour"  value="Hour" >
        <input type="button" class="submitButton" name="Day"   value="Day" >
        <input type="button" class="submitButton" name="Week"  value="Week" >
        <input type="button" class="submitButton" name="Month" value="Month" >
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".submitButton").click(function(event) {
  var _getValue = $(this).val();
  // Rest of the code.
  // Use this _getValue to send to request the ajax
})
```

Answer (score 0):

add class attribute

```
 <form id="formoid" action="testGraph.php" title="" method="post">
       <div>
            <input type="submit" class="submitButton" name="Hour"  value="Hour" >
            <input type="submit" class="submitButton" name="Day"   value="Day" >
            <input type="submit" class="submitButton" name="Week"  value="Week" >
            <input type="submit" class="submitButton" name="Month" value="Month" >
        </div>
 </form>
```

instead of submit use click to trigger ajax request

```
  /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $(".submitButton").click(function(event) {

      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();
            /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
      var $form = $('#formoid'),
          url = $form.attr( 'action' );
      /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
      var posting = $.post( url, { filter: $(this).val() } );
      /* Alerts the results */
       alert($(this).val());
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        alert('success');

      });
    });
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/giantomakin/umvjps9r/

Comment: now by doing this it fixes the ability to recognize which button was clicked do I need to manually reload the section of the page or how does that work.  I posted the value I want to filter by & called the same PHP file I'm currently on - it runs the query then does it re-execute that html? i.e. the  <div style="width:40%; min-width:450px;"> 
            <?php echo $out; ?> 
        </div>

Comment: every time a button is click it will send a ajax request. what do you want from here? every time you trigger a button click it will reload the page? you can check your console it send request every click.

Comment: best thing to do is separate your php file.

Comment: what this is doing is like updating a graph. So say I want to see a weekly filter of followers or monthly or daily.  That's what these buttons are for. So more or less I ping the DB for a new set of data when they hit that button... So I need to recreate the graph with the new data.  Or what would be smarter.. should I grab all the data in 1 pull then just update using javascript on button press?  Thoughts?  Even with the 2nd method how do I go about doing that? It's a php generated graph as you can see from the code.